# How to combine multiple rows into one with no duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has names and identification numbers, though the identification numbers are the same the names are sometimes spelled differently. It looks like this:

```
no_ Name 
1   cat
1   cat
2   dog
2   dog
2   dg
3   rat
```

I have tried this but it does not remove the duplicates

```
SELECT Main.no_,
    LEFT(Main.gls,Len(Main.gls)-1) As "gls"
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT GL2.no_, 
            (
                SELECT GL1.name + ',' AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.gl GL1
                WHERE GL1.no_ = GL2.no_
                ORDER BY GL1.no_
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ) [gls]
        FROM dbo.gl GL2
    ) [Main]
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
no_ Name 
1   cat
2   dog,dg
3   rat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` in the subquery:

```
        (SELECT GL1.name + ',' AS [text()]
         FROM dbo.gl GL1
         WHERE GL1.no_ = GL2.no_
         GROUP BY GL1.name
         ORDER BY MIN(GL1.no_)
         FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) [gls]
```

Comment: this results in the error :Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using cte and string_agg()

```
with glcte(no_, Name) as
(
select no_, Name
from gl
group by no_, Name
)
select no_, string_agg(Name, ",")
from glcte
group by no_
```

Answer (score 0):

-- check this solution a simpler approach , it looks like you need to group by no_ first
--Also see the xml node that you need to start from

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmp
      (no_ int ,NAME varchar(100)) 
     INSERT INTO #tmp
    (
        no_,
        NAME
    )
    VALUES
    (1,   'cat')
    ,(1,   'cat')
    ,(2,   'dog')
    ,(2,   'dog')
    ,(2,   'dg')
    ,(3,   'rat')


    DECLARE @vName VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @tblDistinctno table(no_ int ,NAME varchar(500))  


    INSERT INTO @tblDistinctno
    SELECT   no_ , Name FROM #tmp
    GROUP BY  no_ , Name


    SELECT   no_,SUBSTRING(Name,0,LEN(name)) 
   FROM 
    (
   SELECT DISTINCT o.no_ ,Name = STUFF((
     SELECT name +',' FROM @tblDistinctno i
    WHERE o.no_ = i.no_ 
    -- ORDER BY i.no_
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') FROM @tblDistinctno o
   GROUP BY o.no_ 
   )t





    DROP TABLE #tmp
```